# Angular compare array and update one of it

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have this two sets of array, I need to compare them and if the object from 2th array found on 1st array, I need to update the status on 1st array to true. On angular how to massage the data, thanks!

Below are sample of array,

```
arr1 = [
  {id: 1, status: false},
  {id: 2, status: false},
  {id: 3, status: false}
];

arr2 = [
  {id: 4},
  {id: 5},
  {id: 2}
];
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I am new to angular, so I found a lot foreach guide but I am still confused, so I not sure how loop both of the arrays and compare it.

Comment: There is nothing here specific to Angular, this is just basic JavaScript. *What* guide, and how have you tried to adapt it to your needs?

Comment: you can do it in javascript

Comment: because I am totally new on javascript too...so I really need some sample code and guidance here....I am quite urgent on this issue, thanks guys

Comment: On that front, note: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) If you don't know JS, you won't get far with TypeScript, Angular or anything else built on top of it, so you'll need to *start learning it*. Start with something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have not provided any (faulty) code from yourself, I understand that it sometimes can be difficult to even begin with such a thing.

In this case, you should find a beginning point. You can use the source array (`arr1`) as starting point, or `arr2`. If `arr2` is tiny, it's quicker to use this as starting point. The bigger arr2 gets, the more you might want to start with `arr1`, because that solution is more readable (subjective).

With `arr2` as starting point, you can use the `forEach` method, in combination with `find`:

```
arr2.forEach((item) => {
  const target = arr1.find(({ id }) => item.id === id);

  if (target) {
    target.status = true;
  }
});
```

With the `arr1` as starting point, you can use the `map` method. This will make a new array in place, which is usually a good thing to do, considering angular's change detection system:

```
arr1 = arr1.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  status: arr2.some(({ id }) => item.id === id)
});
```

This will also create a new object reference. Depending on your data set, performance might be an issue, but this will only be noticable if you are processing +10.000 objects (depending on the complexity of your objects).

If you do not want a `status: true` be overwritten to `false` on `arr1`, you need to add an extra condition:

```
arr1 = arr1.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  status: item.status || arr2.some(({ id }) => item.id === id)
});
```

Comment: Hi just now I found out some mistake I did. Now the only problem left is how to update the arr1 after getting the target correctly?